# Can't catch database exception in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have two models, `App\User` and `App\ChatLog`

Model `App\User` has method:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

        
    class User extends Model
    {
    
    ...
    
    public function chatLogs()
        {
            try {
                return $this->hasMany("App\ChatLog_WRONG", "user_id");
            } catch (QueryException $exception) {
                Log::error($exception->getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    
    ...
    
    }
```

I am calling this from controller:

```php
    dd(User::find(1)->chatLogs);
```

I receive this error:

```
Class `App\ChatLog_WRONG` not found
```

Question:
Why I don't get `null` instead of error above?

Comment: Do you have the `App\ChatLog_WRONG` class, if so, then regenerate the classes as `composer dump-autoload`, if not work, then   this line `hasMany("App\ChatLog_WRONG", "user_id")` change to `hasMany(ChatLog_WRONG::class, "user_id")` and add `use App\ChatLog_WRONG;` on the top and try again.

Comment: Show us the `ChatLog_WRONG` class with namespaces

Comment: @sta ChatLog_WRONG class not exists in my project, it's created to test "try-catch" statement

Comment: Can I know, why you need to check the model class?

Comment: @sta Ookay, I think I didn't understand something... where can i find information about what errors should I catch in model?

Comment: You can check a table, exist or not. But not the model.

Comment: you also can use general exception class:
catch (\Exception $exception) {\\your code}